# Парсинг строки таблицы <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток!
Есть некая таблица 4x4, необходимо выбрать строку и разбить столбцы, выбранной строки(выбранной строке присваивается уникальный идентификатор "tabindex=0").

*Мое решение:*

```
$("tbody").click(function () {
        var itemId = $("tbody").find("[tabindex='0']").find("td:eq(0)").html(); // первый элемент td
        var itemOb = $("tbody").find("[tabindex='0']").find("td:eq(1)").html(); // второй элемент td
        var itemCn = $("tbody").find("[tabindex='0']").find("td:eq(2)").html(); // третий элемент td
        var itemZn = $("tbody").find("[tabindex='0']").find("td:eq(3)").html(); // четвертый элемент td
    });
```

Может можно сделать как-то лучше, а еще в моем варианте, при клике каждый раз будет выбираться значение выбранной строки, как сделать так что бы значение выбиралось один раз?

Comment: `разбить столбцы, выбранной строки` - куда разбить? для чего разбить? Что вообще значит "разбить столбцы"?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, возможно не правильно выразился, но я думал по коду будет очевидно. Есть строка таблицы <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>. Значение столбцов(1-4) необходимо извлечь , для дальнейшей работы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Сохранить тело вашей таблице в переменную, искать в переменной

```js
var tbody = $("tbody").find("[tabindex='0']");
var alreadyClicked = false;
$("tbody").click(function() {
  if (!alreadyClicked) {
    alreadyClicked = true;
    var itemId = tbody.find("td:eq(0)").html(); // первый элемент td
    var itemOb = tbody.find("td:eq(1)").html(); // второй элемент td
    var itemCn = tbody.find("td:eq(2)").html(); // третий элемент td
    var itemZn = tbody.find("td:eq(3)").html(); // четвертый элемент td
    console.log(itemId);
    console.log(itemOb);
    console.log(itemCn);
    console.log(itemZn);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table rules="all" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr tabindex="0">
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>Ob</td>
      <td>Cn</td>
      <td>Zn</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

2) Если некритично работать не с кучей переменных, а с объектом, то можно еще сделать так:

```js
var tbody = $("tbody").find("[tabindex='0']");
var alreadyClicked = false;
$("tbody").click(function() {
  if (!alreadyClicked) {
    alreadyClicked = true;
    var item = {};
    var keys = ['id', 'ob', 'ch', 'zn'];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      item[keys[i]] = tbody.find("td:eq(" + i + ")").html();
    }
    console.log(item);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table rules="all" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr tabindex="0">
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>Ob</td>
      <td>Cn</td>
      <td>Zn</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Изначально, я пытался сделать так же, как и Вы в первом примере. Но почему-то у меня данный код не срабатывает...

Comment: @Tibomso , добавил HTML  в сниппеты

Comment: Да, всё работает. А если не секрет, можете подсказать, как сделать так, что бы код выполнялся один раз при клике, что-то на подобие "break" в условии? Можете просто дать ссылку где копать. Я просто с jquery не давно начал работу.

Comment: @Tibomso, вам нужно, чтобы после клика переменные заполнялись один раз, а при повторном уже ничего не происходило?

Comment: Да, просто задача следующая, сделать из строк таблицы заголовок, в принципе я решил так - 1) Создал скрытый заголовок `<h4 id="id" style="display:none" class="col-md-3">Id:</h4>` и затем в функции присваиваю ему значение `$("#id").html('Id: ' + itemId).show();`

Comment: Добавляете обычную флаговую (булеву) переменную, в которой отслеживаете, был ли клик. Если был - то ничего не делаем. Поправил сниппеты.